# CLEM Forecast Script in SPSS Modeler

Tags: python, spss, spss-modeler

I'm struggling with a forecast script that I found in a modeler cookbook, it should be easy to solve but this was away too long ago i did this type of thing.

**Error message: Expected a number in the range '1' to '0' but found '1'**

The script determine the number of rows to be forecast and read it in to a local variable (num_recs) and iterate the score from a neuralnet model, after each succesful scoring it runs a new row to be scored. The result is a 7 day forcast.

Here is the script piece. I would appreciate if someone could take a look at it asap, due to short timeframe(that is tomorrow, friday), that would be much appriated.

```
var num_recs
var idx

execute rec_count_table

> # count the number of records to be forecast

set num_recs = value rec_count_table.output at 1 1
clear outputs

for idx from 1 to num_recs

> # generate forecast one record at a time

    execute forecast_data_overwrite
end for
```

Comment: thx for editing figurine

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue.  I changed the `select_forecast_recs` node to `'Power Demand' = '$null$' vs. @NULL('Power Demand')`.

Hope this helps because the `@NULL('Power Demand')` code did not work for me.

Dale.